# Comparing a boolean array with a list of boolean arrays and returning the index (non-elementwise comparrison)

Tags: python, numpy, boolean

If I have a boolean array (A) and want to compare it with a list of boolean arrays (B):

```
A = array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True])

B = [array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True]), 
     array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True]),
     array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False])]
```

I want to return the index where the two arrays match (whole array comparison not elementwise comparison) e.g. how would I get the output = [False, True, False] or [0, 1, 0] would also be acceptable?

Comment: (A == B).all(1)

Comment: By `array`, you refer to a numpy array? Or to a list?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need first check this two array then use `.all(axis=1)` for check each row like below:

```
>>> from numpy import array
>>> A = array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True])

>>> B = [array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True]), 
...      array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True]),
...      array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False])]


>>> A == B
array([[ True,  True, False,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [ True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True],
       [False,  True,  True,  True,  True,  True, False]])


>>> (A == B).all(1)
array([False,  True, False])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
from numpy import array
import numpy as np

A = array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True])
B = [array([ True,  True,  True, False, False, False,  True]), 
    array([ True,  True, False, False, False, False,  True]),
    array([False,  True, False, False, False, False, False])]


res = []

for x in B:
    res.append(np.array_equal(A, x))

print(res)
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).